# Cleaner way of writing these functions to check if numbers are consecutive in ascending/ descending order

Tags: javascript

I have two functions, one that checks if the passed in string contains consecutive ascending numbers, the other checks for descending consecutive numbers.

I'm wondering if these functions can be rewritten to be cleaner/ shorter than they are in their current state. At present, they're not DRY as logic is reused between the two.

The value passed in will always be a string of 6 characters, e.g "123456".

```
function ascendingNumbers(value) {
  const valueArray = value.split("").map((item) => {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
  });

  let match = 0;

  if (valueArray[1] - 1 === valueArray[0]) {
    match++;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < valueArray.length - 1; i++) {
    valueArray[i + 1] !== valueArray[i] + 1 ? null : match++;
  }
  if (match === 6) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```
function descendingNumbers(value) {
  const valueArray = value.split("").map((item) => {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
  });

  let match = 0;

  if (valueArray[1] + 1 === valueArray[0]) {
    match++;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < valueArray.length - 1; i++) {
    valueArray[i + 1] !== valueArray[i] - 1 ? null : match++;
  }
  if (match === 6) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You only need to implement one of those checks, if you want to test for the opposite, then simply _reverse_ your input data first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: do you want only a single function which checks either ascending/descending values? or just two functions?

Comment: ... or use variables with corresponding values where `+-1` is used.

Comment: a single function would be preferable

Comment: That `if (valueArray[1] - 1 === valueArray[0]) { match++; }` doesn't really make sense. Instead of checking the relation between first and second element twice (once in the if and once in the loop), you should just check whether there are `5` matches between consecutive numbers

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve this in a compact way, we'd create an *ensureOrder* function for this purpose.

You could also do this in an even more compact way with regex, using a positive lookahead to ensure we have 6 digits, then check for a range of optional digits.

```js
function ensureOrder(value, length, ascending) {
  const valueArray = Array.prototype.map.call(value, Number);
  if (valueArray.length !== length) return false;
  return !!valueArray.reduce((last, current, index) => ((last !== null) && (ascending ? current > last: current < last)) ? current: null);
}

console.log("Test ascending:")
let testAsc = ["345678", "123456", "456789", "123458", "223456", "1", "654321", "1234567", "string1"];
testAsc.forEach(input => console.log("Test for "+ input + ": ", ensureOrder(input, 6, true)))

console.log("Test descending:")
let testDesc = ["654321", "765432", "987654", "987321", "123456", "6", "9876543", "string1"];
testDesc.forEach(input => console.log("Test for "+ input + ": ", ensureOrder(input, 6, false)))

// Regex flavour of ascending function
function isAscending(value) {
  return /^(?=\d{6}$)0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?$/.test(value);
}

// Regex flavour of descending function
function isDescending(value) {
  return /^(?=\d{6}$)9?8?7?6?5?4?3?2?1?0?$/.test(value);
}

console.log("Test ascending (regex):")
testAsc.forEach(input => console.log("Test for "+ input + ": ", isAscending(input)))

console.log("Test descending (regex):")
testDesc.forEach(input => console.log("Test for "+ input + ": ", isDescending(input)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this kind of approach which will tell us whether we are the number in ascending or descending order

```
AscendingOrDescending = (inputString) =>  {
    const arrayOfNumbers= Array.from(inputString);
  const asscendingResult = arrayOfNumbers.every((number,index,array) => { 
                return index < array.length ? Number(number) + 1 === Number(array[index+1]) || Number(number) - 1 === Number(array[index-1]) : true;
        });
  return asscendingResult ? 'string is in ascending or descending order' : 'string is not in ascending or descending order'      
}
console.log(AscendingOrDescending("123456"))
```